# Create new parent and childs on the same razor page

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I know this is an existing question, but I haven't seen one that answers to my scenario in asp.net core 2.1 mvc. Also, I'm a pretty noob in this area and this is my very first question here, so sorry in advance. The question is simple (I guess): using asp-net core 2.1 and mvc, how do I create a razor page for the create method where I can create either the parent and the child relationship dynamically on the client side, receiving all data in the post on server? What I have so far (simple code):

The parent model:

```
    public class BusinessCategory
        {
            public BusinessCategory()
            {
                SubBusinessCategories = new List<SubBusinessCategory>();
            }

            [Key]
            public long ID { get; set; }

            public string Code { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<SubBusinessCategory> SubBusinessCategories { get; set; }
        }
```

The child model:

```
public class SubBusinessCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public long BusinessCategoryID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BusinessCategoryID")]
        public virtual BusinessCategory BusinessCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

The ViewModel (I think this is wrong... but it's me trying to get something):

```
public class BusinessCategoryViewModel
    {
        public BusinessCategory BusinessCategory { get; set; }
        public List<SubBusinessCategory> SubBusinessCategories { get; set; }
    }
```

Parent GET Create action in controller:

```
[BindProperty]
public BusinessCategoryViewModel BusinessCategoryVM { get; set; }

public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View(BusinessCategoryVM);
}
```

Create view:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="p-4 border rounded">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="BusinessCategory.Code" class="control-label"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input asp-for="BusinessCategory.Code" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="BusinessCategory.Code" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        //
        // all other properties...
        //
        <br />
        <h2 class="text-info">CHILDS</h2>
        <input type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addSubBusinessCategory()" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="subBusinessCategories" class="p-4 border rounded">
            // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO ADD THE CHILDS 
        </div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I know I'm missing a lot of stuff... Do I have to use a partial view for the childs and append them with ajax calls and jquery, or something else? Is there anyone that can guide me in the right way, please?

Comment: I would suggest using @Html.RenderPartial("ViewName") would be the best way if it is loading at the same time the page renders else we have to go with the ajax call and rendering the partial view.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same issue when starting, so there are a couple of things you can do. There are solutions out there for these so I'll just write out general steps.

**Vanilla JS**

I'd think this good for a simple solution, if you are not doing much with the list. And just need to remove or add a record.

1. Have an index of how many rows you have
2. When you click a button append a pre-written input to a container
3. Then you can use the index to remove the children, make a data-index, attribute.

`container.appendChild("<input name="SubBusinessCategories[index].Property" />")`

**Ajax Request (fetch)**

Similar to Vanilla JS but this time your template lives in a `PartialView.cshtml`. This is good if you need to run some back-end code before rendering the template or somehow populating the values in the template.

1. You would still need to store the `index` in this case and pass it to the back end before rendering.

`fetch(UrlToGetPartial).then(res => {container.appendChild(res)})`

**Note:** if you are going to start removing records, you will need to amend the index in each record. To say if you have 5 in a list, index 0 to 4. if you remove 1, you will end up with 0, 2, 3, 4. So when submitting this you will only receive 1 record at index 0.

**JS Framework (Vue)**

Probably the easiest one to get up and running, just add the library file to your project. This is pretty powerful and keeps your code cleaner than the other solutions.

Your Javascript

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#subBusinessCategories',
    data: {
        rows: []
    },
    methods: {
         addRow(){
             this.rows.push(this.rows.length)
         },
         removeRow(index){
             this.rows.splice(index, 1)
         },
         createName(index, property) {
              return 'SubBusinessCategories[' + index + '].' + property;
         }
    }
})
```

In your HTML

```
<div id="subBusinessCategories" class="p-4 border rounded">
     <button v-on:click="addRow()">Add</button>
     <div v-for="(el, index) in rows">
           <input v-bind:name="createName(index, 'Code')" />
           <button v-on:click="removeRow(index)">Add</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

PS: None of this is tested. The Vue solution is not ideal, but will do for a beginner, and still allows you to leverage Razor.